# psql: connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, psql

I checked a lot on the Internet to fix the problem but couldn't do anything.

First of all, I changed my configuration based on here.

```
    listen_addresses = '*'
    port= 5432
    data_directory = '/var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main'
    unix_socket_directories = '/var/run/postgresql,/tmp'    # comma-separated list >
                                            # (change requires restart)
    unix_socket_group = ''                  # (change requires restart)
    unix_socket_permissions = 0777          # begin with 0 to use octal notation
                                            # (change requires restart)
    bonjour = off                           # advertise server via Bonjour
                                            # (change requires restart)
    bonjour_name = ''               
    ali@ali:~$ sudo systemctl restart postgresql
    ali@ali:~$ psql
    $ psql
    psql: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?
    ali@ali:~$ export PGHOST=localhost
    ali@ali:~$ psql
    psql: connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused
        Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

```
my hba file:
<pre>
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
host   all             postgres                                peer 
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0              md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
host    all             all             192.168.1.0/24          md5

ali@ali:$~ sudo ufw allow 5432
ali@ali:$~ sudo ufw status
WARN: /etc is world writable!
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
5432/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere                  
5432                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
5433                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
5432/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
5432 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
5433 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             

ali@ali:$~ netstat -lntu
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:46589         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:36287         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:37915         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:40483         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:42069           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9050          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:2628          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::1716                 :::*                    LISTEN     
udp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:631             0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:42069           0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:60941           0.0.0.0:*                          
udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*                               
udp6       0      0 :::56614                :::*                               
udp6       0      0 :::1716                 :::*
```

It seems port 5432 is not open, I couldn't open the port anyway :( I also changed the permissions by chmod to 777 I don't know what should i do. Ubuntu version 20.04.03 Postgradesql version: 9.3 I had the same problem when I installed postgradesql 14 or 15 or 16 ...

```
    ● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
         Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
         Active: active (exited) since Thu 2023-12-28 19:41:15 +0330; 4min 45s ago
        Process: 1002 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
       Main PID: 1002 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
            CPU: 2ms
```

output of pg_lsclusters

```
    Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory               Log file
    9.3 main    5432 down   postgres /var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.3-main.log
```

There is nothing on postgresql-9.3-main.log ... :(

I downloaded postgrade from the official repo.

```
    # Create the file repository configuration:
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb https://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt $(lsb_release -cs)-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list'

# Import the repository signing key:
wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -

# Update the package lists:
sudo apt-get update

apt-get install postgresql-9.3, postgresql-client-9.3, libpq-dev
```

Ubuntu 20.04.03 Dec 28 20:39:43 abolfazl-Lenovo-ideapad-310-15ISK

> postgresql@9.3-main[917]: Insecure directory in $ENV{PATH} while running with -T switch at /usr/sha> Dec 28 20:39:43 abolfazl-Lenovo-ideapad-310-15ISK systemd[1]: postgresql@9.3-main.service: Can't open PID file /run/postgresql/9.3-main.pid (yet?) af> Dec 28 20:39:43 abolfazl-Lenovo-ideapad-310-15ISK systemd[1]: postgresql@9.3-main.service: Failed with result 'protocol'. Dec 28 20:39:43 abolfazl-Lenovo-ideapad-310-15ISK systemd[1]: Failed to start PostgreSQL Cluster 9.3-main.

**Latest Update:**
I have the same problem when I use postgradesql 16...

after removing:

```
    sudo apt-get --purge remove postgresql postgresql-*
    dpkg -l | grep postgres ( returns nothing )
```

and Installing:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb https://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt $(lsb_release -cs)-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list'
wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install postgresql
```

Comment: 1) To your question add the output of `pg_lsclusters`. 2) Also what repo you are getting the Postgres packages from. 3) FYI, Postgres 9.3 is 5 years past EOL.

Comment: I edited the question, Check it out :) @AdrianKlaver
I had the same problem when I use postgrade 15 or 14 or 16 ...

Comment: 1) What version of Ubuntu  2) What does `sudo systemctl -l status postgresql@9.3-main.service` return?

Comment: "There is nothing on postgresql-9.3-main.log"  Does it exist at all?  What are the owner and permissions?  The file timestamp?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04.03
Dec 28 20:39:43 abolfazl-Lenovo-ideapad-310-15ISK postgresql@9.3-main[917]: Insecure directory in $ENV{PATH} while running with -T switch at /usr/sha>
Dec 28 20:39:43 abolfazl-Lenovo-ideapad-310-15ISK systemd[1]: postgresql@9.3-main.service: Can't open PID file /run/postgresql/9.3-main.pid (yet?) af>
Dec 28 20:39:43 abolfazl-Lenovo-ideapad-310-15ISK systemd[1]: postgresql@9.3-main.service: Failed with result 'protocol'.
Dec 28 20:39:43 abolfazl-Lenovo-ideapad-310-15ISK systemd[1]: Failed to start PostgreSQL Cluster 9.3-main. @AdrianKlaver

Comment: Yes, It exists at all. I did this for the permissions now.
sudo chmod 777 /var/log/postgresql/ 
sudo chmod 755 /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.3-main.log
@jjanes

Comment: Unless there is existing data in the 9.3 cluster that needs to be preserved, I certainly wouldn't bother to debug this issue against 9.3.  Use a supported version.  It seems like the problem is coming before the logging system gets fully set up.  Try looking in /var/syslog to see if there are any relevant messages there, and if not then try to start the server manually, something like `/path/to/version/bin/postgres -D /path/to/data`.  I wouldn't expect that succeed, but it could give you a useful error message.

Comment: That does not look like output from `systemctl -l status postgresql@9.3-main.service`. It looks more like something from `journalctl`.

Comment: postgres@abolfazl-Lenovo-ideapad-310-15ISK:~$ /usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/pg_ctl restart -D /var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main
pg_ctl: PID file "/var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main/postmaster.pid" does not exist
Is server running?
starting server anyway
pg_ctl: could not read file "/var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main/postmaster.opts"
@AdrianKlaver

Comment: Looks to me like you have been mucking around with the permissions on the Postgres directories. I'm with @jjanes, unless you have a need for the cluster running I would start over. This assumes you  a have backup of the data.

Comment: I removed and Installed the latest version (16) still I have the same problem ...
@jjanes Ubuntu 20.04.03
I don't know how to config the permissions as well. Can you help me more about that?

Comment: Removed what? Problem with Postgres 16 or 9.3 or both? Show your work in the question.

Comment: The permissions come correctly set, just don't mess them up.  After removing the software, use apt purge to remove the data files. Then when you install it again, it creates a new data folder with the correct permission.  Of course only do this if you don't need to save the data.

Comment: I have the same problem with both, I updated the question. Check out the latest update.
@AdrianKlaver

Comment: What does `pg_lsclusters` show now?

Comment: /var/run/postgresql:5432 - no response @AdrianKlaver

Comment: What is `/var/run/postgresql:5432` supposed to be? I asked for the output of `pg_lsclusters`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory              Log file
16  main    5432 down   postgres /var/lib/postgresql/16/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-16-main.log

Comment: See this Also:
abolfazl@abolfazl-Lenovo-ideapad-310-15ISK:~$ sudo pg_ctlcluster 16 main start
Insecure directory in $ENV{PATH} while running with -T switch at /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 383.
@AdrianKlaver

Comment: 1) Why do you  insist on putting the information in your comments instead of the question. 2) It looks to me like you have a security module like  AppArmor running, that is preventing access to the Postgres directories.